# Code generated from Postman doesn't work properly in Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, postman, okhttp

I have API service written on Python, and documentation for it in Postman. All requests in Postman works good, but Java code(with OkHttp library) generated from file uploading request returning "Internal Server Error", i have checked server logs, and find that file wasn't delivered, it crashed before enter in views.py.

Request screenshots from Postman(Token and address are hidden, but they proper)

Screenshots from Postman :

1) [Headers screenshot](https://pp.vk.me/c638324/v638324511/10509/Apsl1i7lw38.jpg)

2) [Body screenshot](https://pp.vk.me/c638324/v638324511/104ff/6C9jN-kudB4.jpg)

Java Code

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run(String fileName) throws IOException {

        String url = "http://*****:8025/v1/add_new_record/";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file_url", file.getName(),
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file))

                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(formBody)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Token *****")
                .build();
        Response response = this.client.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.i("data",response.message());}
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40524159/4238189

Comment: @mablevj ,  but i am adding file to request, not json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works properly, i just forget to add Read/Write Permissions.