# Sending different format json to Okhttp

Tags: android, json, okhttp

for normal `json` like

```
{
    "text1":"going",
    "text2":"sending"
}
```

i'm using `okhttp3` as

```
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                  .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                  .addFormDataPart("text1",xxx)
                  .addFormDataPart("text2","yyy")
                  .build();
```

how do i use it to send for jsons like

```
{"Text1":"aaa","text2":[{"module":"bbb","Text":"xxx","params":{"lang": "eng"}}]}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523965/sending-json-body-through-post-request-in-okhttp-in-android

Comment: `addFormDataPartc` has nothing to do with JSON. You are not sending JSON this way at all. search for `okhttp send json`. It should take you not more than 30 seconds to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add Gradle depends `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'`

```
public static JSONObject foo(String url, JSONObject json) {
        JSONObject jsonObjectResp = null;

        try {

            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            okhttp3.RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
            okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            String networkResp = response.body().string();
            if (!networkResp.isEmpty()) {
                jsonObjectResp = parseJSONStringToJSONObject(networkResp);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String err = String.format("{\"result\":\"false\",\"error\":\"%s\"}", ex.getMessage());
            jsonObjectResp = parseJSONStringToJSONObject(err);
        }

        return jsonObjectResp;
    }
```